# show li one by one with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a Rotator which would walk through on each li and with delay would show theme one by one. I have the following html structure mixed with php snippets

```
<div class="product_box">
<ul id=products>
<?php foreach ($products as $product):?>
    <li>
        <h3><?php echo $product->name ?></h3>
        <a class= "images" target ="_blank" title="<?php echo $product->name ?>" href ="<?php echo $product->link ?>" >
            <img alt="" src="/img/produkte/<?php echo $product->img ?>">
        </a>
        <a id="button" href = "<?php echo $product->link ?>" target="_blank">Info</a>

    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
</div>
```

and I was starting to build the jquery what looks like

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var totalImages = $("#products > li").length;
    setTimeout(function() {
         $('li:first').fadeIn().next() 
         }, 500);

    });

</script>
```

The problem is that I don't really know how to show the next li and hide the previous.

Comment: Please add "php" tag to the question.

Comment: Better yet, remove the PHP tags from your code; this isn't really a PHP question and you can get the answers you need most easily by posting code that can be pasted and rendered directly into a jsFiddle or similar tool.

Comment: okay I will upload on jsfiddle

Comment: Please check bolow link:

[Help link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148004/jquery-fadein-and-fadeout-lis-and-start-over-at-the-last-li

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it easily by just detaching the first list item and then append it to then end.
I have made a simple example here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9KgTg/)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var firstLi = $('#products li').first().detach(); // Remove the first element
        $('#products').append($(firstLi)); // Add it back to the end
    }, 500);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith19/RgKV9/7/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var totalImages = $("#products > li").length;
        var i = 0
        function li_fader(){
            if (i==totalImages){
                return
            }
            elements = $("#products > li")
            $(elements).fadeOut()
            setTimeout(function() {
                ele = elements[i]
                $(ele).fadeIn()
                i = i + 1
                li_fader()
            }, 500);

        }
        li_fader()​;
    })
```

I have used recursion but with a global variable. The code just calls itself and depending on the value of i, it stops execution